# Rjags installation - Centos7

Tags: r, centos7, jags, rjags

I am running into an error while trying to install rjags. I can run JAGS by typing the command `jags` on the command line. However I dont know where it was installed or how to locate it or what to do next.

```
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rjags_4-12.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 74067 bytes (72 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 72 KB

* installing *source* package ‘rjags’ ...
** package ‘rjags’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
configure: WARNING: pkg-config file for jags 4 unavailable
configure: WARNING: Consider adding the directory containing `jags.pc`
configure: WARNING: to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
configure: Attempting legacy configuration of rjags
checking for jags... /usr/bin/jags
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ -std=gnu++11 accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -std=gnu++11 -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking Console.h usability... no
checking Console.h presence... no
checking for Console.h... no
configure: error: "cannot find header file /usr/include/JAGS/Console.h. Please use pkg-config to locate the JAGS library. See the INSTALL file for details."
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rjags’
```

Comment: Have you followed the steps on the INSTALL guide as suggested in the error message? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rjags/INSTALL. What steps have you completed and which did not work?

Comment: Hi, I am not a tech guy, unless there is code I can copy directly from the INSTALL file, I dont really know how to get JAGs installed. At this point I think it may be better to remove and re-install JAGs. I have `pkgconfig` installed... dont know what to do next